# sqlite 1.0.80.0 .NET 4 and Entity framework

Tags: .net, sqlite, frameworks, entity

I have a weird issue with the sqlite 1.0.80.0(sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.80.0.exe).

First I had sqlite 1.0.66 installed in my Visual Studio 2010 SP1. I uninstalled it in to install the latest version of system.data.sqlite(1.0.80.0). Installation went well not errors. I made a project (console application) and created an entity framework object (.edmx) file. I can easily connect the the sqlite file and generate the model from sqlite database.

The problem starts when I try to run the application that contains a simple LINQ request to get something from the database.  I get the following error:

> **System.Security.VerificationException : Operation could destabilize the runtime.**

I try countless things to see if I could solve the problem. But with no solutions up till now. I tried to use sql server 2008 and it works fine. So there is something wrong with the system.data.sqlite or am I doing something wrong?

For the sake of trying everything I installed the sqlite 1.0.66 back on the visual studio 2010 SP1 and it works with the same project!

Does anybody know the reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it has something to do with using the bundle package. I just did some research on what is the right package/distribution for me and read through [this article](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).

"All the "bundle" packages contain the "System.Data.SQLite.dll" mixed-mode assembly. These packages should only be used in cases where the assembly binary must be deployed to the Global Assembly Cache for some reason (e.g. to support some legacy application on customer machines)."

further...

"Using the Global Assembly Cache (at all) is not recommended; therefore, the "bundle" packages should be avoided unless deemed absolutely necessary."

So giving the XCOPY deployment in conjunction with the native library pre-loading feature a try wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Well, the System.Data.sqlite Team noticed that there was a lot of confusion with the packages and they sorted it out after some time. Now you simply download the correct package of their side and it works just like 1.0.66